Can't Display the Total in a POS system 8086 Assembly
I'm new to 8086 and I have been having trouble with this assignment in trying to display the Total charges. I've been trying to figure out and isolate the Errors. I can't figure out which part makes that has the errors. This is a POS system which main function is to accept at least 2-digit inputs and output 3 digits.
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 64

.DATA


    USER        DB 'CASHIER' ;LOGIN
    PASS        DB '12345'
    NAME_INPUT  DB 7 DUP (?)
    PASS_INPUT  DB 5 DUP (?)

    UP_ERROR    DB 13, 10, "USERNAME OR PASSWORD MAYBE WRONG PLEASE TRY AGAIN $"
    
    TAXAMT  DW 0
    TAX_CAL DW 16
    TAX_MSG DB 13,10,"MEMBER DISCOUNT (15%):$"

    MENU_CHOSEN DB ?
    QUANTITY_CHOSEN DB ?
    PRICE_COUNT DB ?

    QTY     DW ?
    TOTAL       DW ?
    CAL_TAX_TOTAL   DW ?
    SUBTOTAL    DW ?


    USER_MSG    DB 13, 10, "PLEASE ENTER USERNAME: $"
    PASS_MSG    DB 13, 10, "PLEASE ENTER PASSWORD: $"

    MSG DB 13,10, " |  WELCOME to PharmEase POS  |$"
    MENU_CHOOSE DB 13,10, "Please Choose A Number (ENTER 0 FOR MAIN MENU): $"
    PRODUCT_MSG DB 13,10, "Please Choose A Product (IF 1, ENTER 01, MAX:15): $"
    PRODUCT DB 0


    MENU1 DB 13,10, "================================================================="
        DB 13,10, "|        0. EXIT                             |"
        DB 13,10,   "|      1. MEDICATION                       |"
        DB 13,10,   "|          2. SUPPLEMENTS                          |"
        DB 13,10,   "|          3. COSMETICS AND PERSONAL CARE                  |"
        DB 13,10,   "|          4. CHECKOUT                         |$"


    MAIN_MENU DB 13,10,"ENTER 0 TO GO BACK TO MAIN MENU:$"




    FIRSTOPTL1  DB 13,10,"      MEDICATION       |  PRICE (RM)" 
                DB 13,10,"      1. PARACETAMOL                   5.00            "
                DB 13,10,"  2. IBUPROFEN                7.00             " 
                DB 13,10,"  3. CETIRZINE                8.00             "
                DB 13,10,"  4. LOPERAMIDE               8.00             " 
                DB 13,10,"  5. CETIRZINE                9.00             $"

    MED1        DB 13,10,"  1. PARACETAMOL              5.00             $"
    MED2        DB 13,10,"  2. IBUPROFEN                7.00             $" 
    MED3        DB 13,10,"  3. CETIRZINE                8.00             $"
    MED4        DB 13,10,"  4. LOPERAMIDE               8.00             $" 
    MED5        DB 13,10,"  5. CETIRZINE                9.00             $"
        
    MEDPRICE DW 0, 500, 700, 800, 800, 900
    MEDARR  DB 10 DUP (0)
    QTYMED  DB 10 DUP (0)
    MED_COUNT   DB 0
    MED_SEL     DB 0
    MEDQTY_SELEC DB 0



    SECONDOPTL1 DB 13,10,"      SUPPLEMENTS       |  PRICE (RM)" 
                DB 13,10,"      1. VITAMIN C                6.00             "
                DB 13,10,"  2. CALCIUM                  7.00             " 
                DB 13,10,"  3. MAGNEISIUM               8.00             "
                DB 13,10,"  4. IRON                     8.00             " 
                DB 13,10,"  5. MULTIVITAMINS            9.00             $"

                
    SUPP1       DB 13,10,"      1. VITAMIN C           6.00              $"
    SUPP2       DB 13,10,"  2. CALCIUM                  7.00             $" 
    SUPP3       DB 13,10,"  3. MAGNEISIUM               8.00             $"
    SUPP4       DB 13,10,"  4. IRON                     8.00             $" 
    SUPP5       DB 13,10,"  5. MULTIVITAMINS            9.00             $"

    SUPPRICE DW 0, 600, 700, 800, 800, 900
    SUPPARR         DB 10 DUP (0)
    QTYSUPP         DB 10 DUP (0)
    SUPP_COUNT  DB 0
    SUPP_SEL        DB 0
    SUPPQTY_SELEC DB 0

    


    THIRDOPTL1  DB 13,10,"      OTHER       |  PRICE (RM)" 
                DB 13,10,"      1. DETTOL                   5.00             "
                DB 13,10,"  2. NIVEA DEODRANT       7.00             " 
                DB 13,10,"  3. SUNSILK SHAMPOO      9.00             "
                DB 13,10,"  4. DOVE BODY WASH       9.00             " 
                DB 13,10,"  5. GARNIER FACE WASH     9.00            $"

    O1          DB 13,10,"      1. DETTOL           5.00             "
    O2          DB 13,10,"  2. NIVEA DEODRANT       7.00             " 
    O3          DB 13,10,"  3. SUNSILK SHAMPOO      9.00             "
    O4          DB 13,10,"  4. DOVE BODY WASH       9.00             " 
    O5          DB 13,10,"  5. GARNIER FACE WASH     9.00            $"
    
    OTHERPRICE DW 0, 500, 700, 900, 900, 900 
    
    OTHERARR        DB 10 DUP (0)
    QTYOTHER    DB 10 DUP (0)
    OTHER_COUNT DB 0
    OTHER_SEL       DB 0
    OTHERQTY_SELEC DB 0

    

    
    PRODUCTARR DB 10 DUP (0)
    PRODUCTPRICE DW 20 DUP (0)
    PRODUCTQTY DB 10 DUP (0)
    PRODUCT_COUNT   DB 0
    PRODUCT_SELECTED    DB ?
    PRICE   DW 0

    FIRST_NUM   DB 0
    SECOND_NUM DB 0


    



    PRINT_CHOOSE DB 13,10, "PLEASE CHOOSE AN AMOUNT IF(:  $"
    
    ERROR_PROD_MSG DB 13,10, "ERROR PLEASE CHOOSE A NUMBER: $"



    NEWLINE DB 13,10, "$"

    CALC_NUM    DW 0
    CALC_SEN    DB 0
    CALC_ARR    DB 5 DUP (?)
    Q_DB        DB 0
    R_DB        DB 0
    Q_DW        DW 0
    R_DW        DW 0
    TEN_DB      DB 10
    TEN_DW      DW 10
    HUNDRED     DB 100
    Q_QTY       DB 0
    R_QTY       DB 0
    
    T_Q1            DW 0
    T_R1            DW 0
    T_Q2            DB 0
    T_R2            DB 0
    T_Q3            DB 0
    T_R3            DB 0
    T_Q4            DB 0
    
    S_Q1            DW 0
    S_R1            DW 0
    S_Q2            DB 0
    S_R2            DB 0
    S_Q3            DB 0
    S_R3            DB 0
    S_Q4            DB 0
    S_Q5            DB 0
    S_Q6            DB 0
    Q           DW ?
    R           DW ?
    
    SUB_TAX     DW 0
    SUBTOTAL_MSG DB 13,10,  "SUBTOTAL(RM):$"

        RECEIPT DB 13,10,"      RECEIPT         "
    
    TOTAL_MSG       DB 13,10,"================================================================================"
                    DB 13,10,"TOTAL: RM $"
    
    
    TAB DB "        "
    
    SUMMARY DB 13,10,"      SUMMARY"
            DB 13,10,"-------------------- $"
    
    SUMMARY_MSG1 DB '   Total sales earn         : RM $'
    SUMMARY_MSG2 DB '   Total number of Customer : $'


.CODE
MAIN PROC

    MOV AX,@DATA
    MOV DS, AX

    ;CALL CLS

START_LOGIN:
 CALL LOGIN

START:
    CALL CLEAR
    CALL DISPLAY_MENU

COMP_MENU:
    CMP PRODUCT, '0'
    JE EXIT1

    CMP PRODUCT, '1'
    JE FIRSTOP

    CMP PRODUCT, '2'
    JE SECONDOP

    CMP PRODUCT, '3'
    JE THIRDOP

    CMP PRODUCT, '4'
    JE CHECKOUT

    JNE ERROR_PRODUCT


FIRSTOP:
    CALL CLEAR
    CALL PRINT_FIRST
    CALL GET_INPUT

    JMP START



SECONDOP:
    CALL CLEAR
    CALL PRINT_SECOND
    CALL GET_INPUT

    JMP START


THIRDOP:
    CALL CLEAR
    CALL PRINT_THIRD
    CALL GET_INPUT

    JMP START




ERROR_PRODUCT:
    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX, NEWLINE
    INT 21H


    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX, ERROR_PROD_MSG
    INT 21H


CHECKOUT:
    CALL CLEAR
    CALL PRINT_CHECKOUT

EXIT1:
    CALL EXIT


MAIN ENDP


LOGIN PROC
LOGIN:
    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX, MSG
    INT 21H


    MOV AH, 09H
    LEA DX, USER_MSG  ; PRINT PLEASE ENTER USERNAME:
    INT 21H

    MOV AX, 0

    MOV CX, 7  ;SET COUNTER 7 FOR USERNAME LOOP
    MOV SI, 0   ; SET SI 0 FOR ARRAY INPUT

GET_NAME:
    MOV AH, 01H
    INT 21H

    INC SI
    MOV NAME_INPUT[SI], AL
    LOOP GET_NAME

    MOV AH, 09H
    LEA DX, PASS_MSG ;PRINT PLEASE ENTER PASSWORD:
    INT 21H

    MOV AX, 0

    MOV CX, 5 ;SET COUNTER 7 FOR USERNAME LOOP
    MOV SI, 0 ; SET SI 0 FOR ARRAY INPUT

GET_PASS:

    MOV AH, 01H
    INT 21H

    MOV PASS_INPUT[SI], AL
    INC SI
    LOOP GET_PASS

    MOV SI, 0
    MOV DI, 0

CHECK_NAME:
    CMP SI, 5
    JE CHECK_PASS

    MOV AL, NAME_INPUT[SI]
    CMP AL, NAME_INPUT[SI]
    JE CHKNEXT_NAME
    JNE LOGIN_ERROR

CHKNEXT_NAME:
    INC SI
    JMP CHECK_NAME

CHECK_PASS:
    CMP DI, 5
    JE DISPLAY_MENU

    MOV AL, PASS[DI]
    CMP AL, PASS_INPUT[DI]
    JE CHKNEXT_PASS
    JNE LOGIN_ERROR

CHKNEXT_PASS:
    INC DI
    JMP CHECK_PASS

LOGIN_ERROR:
    MOV AH, 09H
    LEA DX, UP_ERROR
    INT 21H

    JMP LOGIN
LOGIN ENDP

DISPLAY_MENU PROC
DISPLAY_MENU:
    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX,NEWLINE   ;NEWLINE
    INT 21H

    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX, MSG
    INT 21H

    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX, MENU1
    INT 21H

    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX,NEWLINE   ;NEWLINE
    INT 21H

    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX, MENU_CHOOSE
    INT 21H


    MOV AH, 01H         ;INPUT Products
    INT 21H
    
    MOV PRODUCT, AL 


RET

DISPLAY_MENU ENDP


PRINT_FIRST PROC
    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX, FIRSTOPTL1 ;PRINT FIRST OPTION LIST
    INT 21H

    RET
PRINT_FIRST ENDP

PRINT_SECOND PROC
    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX, SECONDOPTL1 ;PRINT FIRST OPTION LIST
    INT 21H

    RET
PRINT_SECOND ENDP

PRINT_THIRD PROC
    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX, THIRDOPTL1 ;PRINT FIRST OPTION LIST
    INT 21H

    RET
PRINT_THIRD ENDP


GET_INPUT PROC

SHOW_INPUT_MSG: 
    MOV AH, 09H
    LEA DX,  MENU_CHOOSE
    INT 21H
        
    MOV AH, 01H     
    INT 21H
    MOV PRODUCT, AL

    CMP AL, '0'
    JE BACK_MAIN_MENU_POINT

    SUB AL, 30H
    MOV MENU_CHOSEN, AL
            
    MOV AH, 09H
    LEA DX, PRODUCT_MSG
    INT 21H
        
    MOV AH, 01H     
    INT 21H
    SUB AL, 30H
    MOV FIRST_NUM,AL

    
    MOV AH, 01H     
    INT 21H
    SUB AL, 30H
    MOV SECOND_NUM,AL
    
    MOV AX, 0
    MOV AL, FIRST_NUM
    MOV BL, 10
    MUL BL
    MOV FIRST_NUM, AL
    
    MOV AL, FIRST_NUM
    ADD SECOND_NUM, AL
    
    MOV AL, SECOND_NUM
    MOV PRINT_CHOOSE, AL

    CMP PRODUCT, '1'
    JE UP_MEDICAL
        
    CMP PRODUCT, '2'
    JE UP_SUP
        
    CMP PRODUCT, '3'
    JE UP_OTHER
        
BACK_MAIN_MENU_POINT:
    JMP BACK_MAIN_MENU
    
UP_MEDICAL:
    MOV BX, 0
    MOV BL, MED_COUNT

    MOV AL, MENU_CHOSEN
    MOV MEDARR[BX], AL
        
    MOV AL, QUANTITY_CHOSEN
    MOV QTYMED[BX],AL

    INC MED_COUNT

    JMP SHOW_INPUT_MSG
        
UP_SUP:
    MOV BX, 0
    MOV BL, SUPP_COUNT

    MOV AL, MENU_CHOSEN
    MOV SUPPARR[BX],AL
        
    MOV AL,QUANTITY_CHOSEN
    MOV QTYSUPP[BX],AL
        
    INC SUPP_COUNT

    JMP SHOW_INPUT_MSG  
    
UP_OTHER:
    MOV BX, 0
    MOV BL, OTHER_COUNT

    MOV AL, MENU_CHOSEN
    MOV OTHERARR[BX],AL
        
    MOV AL,QUANTITY_CHOSEN
    MOV QTYOTHER[BX],AL
        
    INC OTHER_COUNT

    JMP SHOW_INPUT_MSG

BACK_MAIN_MENU:
    CALL START

    RET


GET_INPUT ENDP

PRINT_CHECKOUT PROC

    MOV AH, 09H
    LEA DX, RECEIPT
    INT 21H
    
    JMP CLEAR_MED_SELECT
    
    
CLEAR_MED_SELECT:
    MOV SI, 0
PRINT_MED_SELECT:   
    MOV AL,MEDARR[SI]
    MOV MED_SEL, AL
    
    MOV AL,QTYMED[SI]
    MOV MEDQTY_SELEC,AL

    CMP MED_SEL,1
    JE PRINT_MED1
    
    CMP MED_SEL,2
    JE PRINT_MED2
    
    CMP MED_SEL,3
    JE PRINT_MED3
    
    CMP MED_SEL,4
    JE PRINT_MED4
    
    CMP MED_SEL,5
    JE PRINT_MED5
    
    
    JNE CLR_SUPP_SELECT
    
FIRSTEXIT:
    CALL EXIT
    
PRINT_QTY:
    MOV AX,0
    MOV AL, MEDQTY_SELEC
    DIV TEN_DB
    
    MOV Q_QTY,AL
    MOV R_QTY,AH
    
    ADD Q_QTY, 30H
    ADD R_QTY, 30H
    
    MOV AH, 02H
    MOV DL, Q_QTY
    INT 21H 

    MOV AH, 02H
    MOV DL, R_QTY
    INT 21H
    
    JMP PRINT_MED
    
PRINT_MED1:
    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX, MED1
    INT 21H

    JMP PRINT_QTY

PRINT_MED2:
    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX, MED2
    INT 21H
    

    
    JMP PRINT_QTY
    
PRINT_MED3:
    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX, MED3
    INT 21H
    
    
    JMP PRINT_QTY
        
PRINT_MED4:
    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX, MED4
    INT 21H
    
    JMP PRINT_QTY


PRINT_MED5:
    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX, MED5
    INT 21H
    
    JMP PRINT_QTY


PRINT_MED:
    INC SI
    JMP PRINT_MED_SELECT
    
CLR_SUPP_SELECT:
    MOV SI, 0
    
PRINT_SUPP_SELECT:  
    MOV AL,SUPPARR[SI]
    MOV SUPP_SEL, AL
    
    MOV AL,QTYSUPP[SI]
    MOV SUPPQTY_SELEC,AL

    CMP SUPP_SEL,1
    JE PRINT_SUPP1
    
    CMP SUPP_SEL,2
    JE PRINT_SUPP2
    
    CMP SUPP_SEL,3
    JE PRINT_SUPP3
    
    CMP SUPP_SEL,4
    JE PRINT_SUPP4
    
    CMP SUPP_SEL,5
    JE PRINT_SUPP5
    
    JNE CLR_OTHER_SELECT
    
SECONDEXIT:
    CALL EXIT
    
PRINT_SUPPQTY:
    MOV AX,0
    MOV AL, SUPPQTY_SELEC
    DIV TEN_DB
    
    MOV Q_QTY,AL
    MOV R_QTY,AH
    
    ADD Q_QTY, 30H
    ADD R_QTY, 30H
    
    MOV AH, 02H
    MOV DL, Q_QTY
    INT 21H 

    MOV AH, 02H
    MOV DL, R_QTY
    INT 21H
    
    JMP PRINT_SUPP
    
PRINT_SUPP1:
    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX, SUPP1
    INT 21H
    
    JMP PRINT_SUPPQTY
    
PRINT_SUPP2:
    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX, SUPP2
    INT 21H
    
    JMP PRINT_SUPPQTY   

PRINT_SUPP3:
    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX, SUPP3
    INT 21H
    
    JMP PRINT_SUPPQTY
        
PRINT_SUPP4:
    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX, SUPP4
    INT 21H
    
    JMP PRINT_SUPPQTY
        
PRINT_SUPP5:
    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX, SUPP5
    INT 21H
    
    JMP PRINT_SUPPQTY
    
PRINT_SUPP:
    INC SI
    JMP PRINT_SUPP_SELECT
    
CLR_OTHER_SELECT:
    MOV SI,0
PRINT_OTHER_SELECT: 
    MOV AL,OTHERARR[SI]
    MOV OTHER_SEL, AL
    
    MOV AL,QTYOTHER[SI]
    MOV OTHERQTY_SELEC,AL

    CMP OTHER_SEL,1
    JE PRINT_O1
    
    CMP OTHER_SEL,2
    JE PRINT_O2

    CMP OTHER_SEL,3
    JE PRINT_O3
    
    CMP OTHER_SEL,4
    JE PRINT_O4

    CMP OTHER_SEL,5
    JE PRINT_O5

    
    JNE PRINT_TOTAL
    
LASTEXIT:
    CALL EXIT
    
PRINT_OTHERQTY:
    MOV AX,0
    MOV AL, OTHERQTY_SELEC
    DIV TEN_DB
    
    MOV Q_QTY,AL
    MOV R_QTY,AH
    
    ADD Q_QTY, 30H
    ADD R_QTY, 30H
    
    MOV AH, 02H
    MOV DL, Q_QTY
    INT 21H 

    MOV AH, 02H
    MOV DL, R_QTY
    INT 21H

    JMP PRINT_OTHER
    
PRINT_O1:
    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX, O1
    INT 21H
    
    JMP PRINT_OTHERQTY

PRINT_O2:
    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX, O2
    INT 21H

    JMP PRINT_OTHERQTY
    

PRINT_O3:
    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX, O3
    INT 21H

    JMP PRINT_OTHERQTY
    

PRINT_O4:
    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX, O4
    INT 21H

    JMP PRINT_OTHERQTY
    
PRINT_O5:
    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX, O5
    INT 21H

    JMP PRINT_OTHERQTY
    
PRINT_OTHER:
    INC SI
    JMP PRINT_OTHER_SELECT

PRINT_TOTAL:
        
    MOV AH, 09H
    LEA DX, TOTAL_MSG
    INT 21H
    
    
    JMP CHK_PRODUCT

FIRST_CAL_NUM:
    MOV SI, 0



CAL_NUM:
    MOV AL, PRODUCTARR[SI]
    MOV PRODUCT_SELECTED , AL
    
    CMP PRODUCT_SELECTED, 0
    JE CHK_PRODUCT
    
    MOV AL, PRODUCT_SELECTED
    MOV BL, 2
    MUL BL
    MOV PRICE_COUNT, AL
    
    MOV BX, 0
    MOV AL, PRICE_COUNT
    MOV BL, AL
    MOV AX , PRODUCTPRICE[BX]   
    MOV PRICE, AX
    
    MOV AX, 0
    MOV AL, PRODUCTQTY[SI]
    MOV QTY, AX
    
    MOV AX, 0
    MOV AX, PRICE
    MUL QTY
    
    ADD TOTAL, AX
    INC SI

    JMP CAL_NUM

LAST_CAL_NUM1:
    JMP LAST_ADD_NUM

CHK_PRODUCT:
    INC PRODUCT_COUNT
    MOV SI, 0
    MOV CX, 10

    CMP PRODUCT_COUNT, 1
    JE CHANGE_MED_PRODUCT

    CMP PRODUCT_COUNT, 2
    JE CHANGE_SUPP_PRODUCT

    CMP PRODUCT_COUNT, 3
    JE CHANGE_OTHER_PRODUCT
    
    JNE LAST_CAL_NUM1

CHANGE_MED_PRODUCT:
    MOV AL, MEDARR[SI]
    MOV PRODUCTARR[SI], AL

    MOV AL, QTYMED[SI]
    MOV PRODUCTQTY[SI], AL
    
    MOV AX, SI
    MOV BL, 2
    MUL BL
    MOV PRICE_COUNT, AL
    
    MOV BX, 0
    MOV BL, PRICE_COUNT
    MOV AX, MEDPRICE[BX]
    MOV MEDPRICE[BX], AX

    INC SI
    LOOP CHANGE_MED_PRODUCT


    JMP FIRST_CAL_NUM

CHANGE_SUPP_PRODUCT:
    MOV AX, 0
    MOV AL, SUPPARR[SI]
    MOV PRODUCTARR[SI], AL
    
    MOV AL, QTYSUPP[SI]
    MOV PRODUCTQTY[SI], AL
    
    MOV AX, SI
    MOV BL, 2
    MUL BL
    MOV PRICE_COUNT, AL
    
    MOV BX, 0
    MOV BL, PRICE_COUNT
    MOV AX, SUPPRICE[BX]
    MOV PRODUCTPRICE[BX], AX

    INC SI
    LOOP CHANGE_SUPP_PRODUCT

    JMP FIRST_CAL_NUM

CHANGE_OTHER_PRODUCT:
    MOV AX, 0
    MOV AL, OTHERARR[SI]
    MOV PRODUCTARR[SI], AL
    
    MOV AL, QTYOTHER[SI]
    MOV PRODUCTQTY[SI], AL
    
    MOV AX, SI
    MOV BL, 2
    MUL BL
    MOV PRICE_COUNT, AL
    
    MOV BX, 0
    MOV BL, PRICE_COUNT
    MOV AX, OTHERPRICE[BX]
    MOV OTHERPRICE[BX], AX

    INC SI
    LOOP CHANGE_OTHER_PRODUCT

    JMP FIRST_CAL_NUM

LAST_ADD_NUM:
    MOV AX, TOTAL
    MOV CALC_NUM, AX
    
    CALL PRINT_NUMBER
    
    JMP PRINT_TAX

    
PRINT_TAX:
    MOV AX,0
    MOV AX,CAL_TAX_TOTAL
    MOV DX,TAX_CAL
    MUL DX
    MOV TAXAMT,AX
    
    MOV DX,0000    
    MOV AX,TAXAMT  
    MOV BX,10      
    DIV BX 
    
    MOV T_R1, DX   
    MOV T_Q1, AX
    
    MOV AX, 0      
    MOV AX, T_Q1 
    mov bl,10     
    DIV bl        
    MOV T_Q2, AL   
    MOV T_R2, AH

    MOV AX,0
    MOV AL,T_Q2  
    mov BL,10    
    DIV BL        
    MOV T_Q3,AL     
    MOV T_Q4,AH  
    
    ADD T_Q3,30H    
    ADD T_Q4, 30H   
    ADD T_R2, 30H    
    ADD T_R1, 30H
    
    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX,TAX_MSG
    INT 21H
    
    MOV AH, 02H
    MOV DL, T_Q3    
    INT 21H

    MOV AH, 02H
    MOV DL, T_Q4    
    INT 21H

    MOV AH, 02H
    MOV DL, '.'
    INT 21H

    MOV AH, 02H
    MOV DL, T_R2    
    INT 21H

    MOV AH, 02H
    MOV DX, T_R1    
    INT 21H
    
    
PRINT_SUBTOTAL: 
    MOV AX,0
    MOV AX,TOTAL        
    ADD TAXAMT,AX       
    
    MOV AX,TAXAMT
    
    MOV SUBTOTAL,0
    MOV SUBTOTAL,AX
    
    MOV DX,0000   
    MOV AX,SUBTOTAL  
    MOV BX,10      
    DIV BX              
    
    MOV S_R1, DX    
    MOV S_Q1, AX    
    
    MOV AX, 0      
    MOV AX, S_Q1    
    mov bl,10       
    DIV bl        
    MOV S_Q2, AL        
    MOV S_R2, AH    

    MOV AX,0            
    MOV AL,S_Q2    
    mov bl,10     
    DIV bl        
    MOV S_Q3,AL     
    MOV S_Q4,AH     
    
    MOV AX,0
    MOV AL,S_Q3
    MOV BL,10
    DIV BL
    MOV S_Q5,AL     
    MOV S_Q6,AH
    
    
    ADD S_Q3,30H    
    ADD S_Q4, 30H   
    ADD S_Q5, 30H
    ADD S_Q6,30H
    ADD S_R2, 30H    
    ADD S_R1, 30H
    
    
    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX,SUBTOTAL_MSG
    INT 21H
    
    MOV AH, 02H
    MOV DL, S_Q5   
    INT 21H

    MOV AH, 02H
    MOV DL, S_Q6  
    INT 21H

    MOV AH,02H
    MOV DL,S_Q4
    INT 21H

    MOV AH, 02H
    MOV DL, '.'
    INT 21H

    MOV AH, 02H
    MOV DL, S_R2  
    INT 21H

    MOV AH, 02H
    MOV DX, S_R1  
    INT 21H
    
    
    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX, MAIN_MENU
    INT 21H
    
    MOV AH, 01H     
    INT 21H
    SUB AL, 30H
        
    CMP AL,0
    
    RET
PRINT_CHECKOUT ENDP

PRINT_NUMBER PROC
    MOV AX, 0

    MOV AX, CALC_NUM
    DIV HUNDRED

    MOV Q_DB, AL
    MOV CALC_SEN, AH

    MOV AX, 0
    MOV AL, Q_DB
    MOV CALC_NUM, AX
    MOV CAL_TAX_TOTAL, AX
    
    MOV SI, 0
    MOV CX, 5
CLEAR_ARR:
    MOV CALC_ARR[SI], ' '
    INC SI
    LOOP CLEAR_ARR

    MOV SI, 4   

    MOV AX, CALC_NUM    
    MOV Q_DW, AX
    MOV Q_DB, AL

    CMP AH, 00H
    JE SBYTEDIV1

    CMP AH, 0AH
    JAE DBYTEDIV1
    JB DBYTEDIV2

SBYTEDIV1:
    MOV AX, 0

    MOV AL, Q_DB        

    DIV TEN_DB
    MOV Q_DB, AL        
    MOV R_DB, AH            

    ADD R_DB, 30H

    MOV AL, R_DB
    MOV CALC_ARR[SI], AL

    DEC SI

    CMP Q_DB, 0
    JE SHOW_ALL_NUM
    JNE SBYTEDIV1

DBYTEDIV1:
    MOV AX, 0
    MOV DX, 0

    MOV AX, Q_DW            

    DIV TEN_DB
    MOV Q_DB, AL                
    MOV R_DB, AH        

    ADD R_DB, 30H
    MOV AL, R_DB
    MOV CALC_ARR[SI], AL

    DEC SI

    JMP SBYTEDIV1   

DBYTEDIV2:
    MOV AX, 0
    MOV DX, 0

    MOV AX, Q_DW                    

    DIV TEN_DW
    MOV Q_DW, AX                
    MOV R_DB, DL        

    ADD R_DB, 30H
    MOV AL, R_DB
    MOV CALC_ARR[SI], AL

    DEC SI

    MOV AX, Q_DW
    CMP AH, 0AH
    JAE DBYTEDIV2
    JB DBYTEDIV1

SHOW_ALL_NUM:
    MOV SI, 0
    MOV CX, 5

NUM_LOOP:
    MOV AH, 02H
    MOV DL, CALC_ARR[SI]
    INT 21H

    INC SI
    LOOP NUM_LOOP

    MOV AH, 02H
    MOV DL, '.'
    INT 21H

    MOV AX, 0
    MOV AL, CALC_SEN    

    DIV TEN_DB
    MOV Q_DB, AL        
    MOV R_DB, AH            

    ADD Q_DB, 30H
    ADD R_DB, 30H
    
    MOV AH, 02H
    MOV DL, Q_DB
    INT 21H
    
    MOV AH, 02H
    MOV DL, R_DB
    INT 21H


    RET

PRINT_NUMBER ENDP


CLEAR PROC
    mov ah, 06h    ; Function to scroll up window
    mov al, 0      ; Clear entire window
    mov bh, 07h    ; Attribute (default white on black)
    mov cx, 0      ; Upper left corner (row 0, column 0)
    mov dx, 184fh  ; Lower right corner (row 24, column 79)
    int 10h        ; BIOS video services interrupt
    ret
CLEAR ENDP

EXIT PROC
MOV AH,4CH
INT 21H

RET
EXIT ENDP



END MAIN

